# How to remove default link in JS text/template

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, backbone.js

Anyone can help me on how to remove or replace existing link in JS templating. I use backbone.js for this.

Here is my code:

```
<script id="option-show-template" type="text/template">
<address>
   <abbr title="Website">Web :</abbr> <%= (website)? '<a href="'+ website +'" id="website">' + website + '</a>' : ''  %></address>
</script>
```

Output:

```
Web: www.test.com
```

The Problem is even though it will output the correct data but the href attr is not totally display the correct one. My localhost/testserver includes in the href attrib.

```
Web: <a href="localhost/testserver/www.test.com">www.test.com</a>
```

What I want is to remove the default base url. Must be output like this way:

```
Web: <a href="www.test.com">www.test.com</a>
```

Answer (score 8):

Add `http://`

Try This

```
 <abbr title="Website">Web :</abbr> <%= (website)? '<a href="http://'+ website +'" id="website">' + website + '</a>' : ''  %></address>
```

Answer (score 7):

**What is wrong here??**

The problem with your implementation is, when you set `href` attribute without any *protocol*(http, https, ftp etc) the browser treat the link as relative path. so when you are viewing the page on `http://localhost/testserver/` the url for your page become `localhost/testserver/www.test.com`

**How to fix??**

In short, to fix the problem you need to add `http://` before your url if there is not any. You can do it in many ways, like :

1. Update your template as ***Nitish Kumar*** suggested.
2. replacing all url prepend with `http://` using jquery
3. .... or many other ways!!!

The option 1 or 2 is easy enough to implement and would solve your problem, if your are sure your `URLs` will be always like your example. But will fail for following use cases:

1. If your url already got a protocol(i.e. `http://google.com`). Then your URL will become `http://http://google.com`
2. If your url is really a relative url(i.e. `my/relative/url`). Then it should be stay as it is but you will get invalid url without a domain - `http://my/relative/url`

**The ultimate solution!!**

So you can use following function to fix your URLS

```
//Check if it is a valid URL with FQDN
function isValidUrl(url) {
    return url.match(/((ftp|http|https):\/\/)?[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+/);
}

//Check if the url already contain a protocol or not
function hasProtocol(url){
    return url.match(/(ftp|http|https):\/\//);
}

//Fix your URL only if needed!!
function setHttp(link) {
    return (!isValidUrl(link) || hasProtocol(link)) ? link : 'http://' + link;
}
```

You can use this function in several way to fix your problem. a sample implementation you can find [here](http://jsfiddle.net/qKbz3/)

Happy coding!!

Answer (score 2):

The href must start with the protocol if you are using an absolute path.  Without the protocol, the browser is going to interpret it as a relative path, leading you to get something like `localhost/testserver/www.test.com`.

I believe the only real solution to this is going to be to add the protocol to your href.

Answer (score 1):

Are you copying the URL out?  `www.test.com` isn't a valid fully qualified URL.  You'll want to prepend `http://` to your URL.  The only other way that could be entering into things is if the 'website' variable contains that information, which I don't quite get from your question.

Your question is phrased a bit oddly and the example you provide isn't quite sufficient to suggest more at this point (although I will say that I generally discourage ternary operations inside of template echos like you've got).

Answer (score 0):

replacing url prepending with http://. This should get your problem solved